# DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher : No event was found for the exception org.spriInternalAuthenticationServiceException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**this error is coming in my spring boot project**

2023-08-21T19:01:36.289+05:30 DEBUG 11176 --- [nio-8484-exec-1] .s.a.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher : No event was found for the exception org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException 2023-08-21T19:01:36.317+05:30 DEBUG 11176 --- [nio-8484-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy : Securing POST /error 2023-08-21T19:01:36.332+05:30 DEBUG 11176 --- [nio-8484-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext

I am storing the refreshtoken in the database when i login with the user for the first time then it show an appropriate response but  I am getting this error with 401 unauthorized when i try to login second time with same user i have used @jsonIgnore at refreshToken mapping in user entity but still getting this error please help anyone

**this error is coming in my spring boot project**

2023-08-21T19:01:36.289+05:30 DEBUG 11176 --- [nio-8484-exec-1] .s.a.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher : No event was found for the exception org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException 2023-08-21T19:01:36.317+05:30 DEBUG 11176 --- [nio-8484-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy : Securing POST /error 2023-08-21T19:01:36.332+05:30 DEBUG 11176 --- [nio-8484-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext

I am storing the refreshtoken in the database when i login with the user for the first time then it show an appropriate response but  I am getting this error with 401 unauthorized when i try to login second time with same user i have used @jsonIgnore at refreshToken mapping in user entity but still getting this error please help anyone

I have tried to put @jsonIgnore annotation as i think that that the problem persist because of the refresh token mapping in the user entity class i have mapped it as @OneToOne but still getting the same error